# loading constraint violation when resolving method "javax/imageio/metadata/IIOMetadata.getAsTree(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/w3c/dom/Node

Tags: java, websphere, classloader, pdfbox

I am using Apahce **Pdfbox 2.0.30** on **Websphere ND 9.0.5.13** which is running on **Java 8**
The application **class loader** is set to **Parent Last**

My POM file is as follows:

```
<dependencies>
    
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    

    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    
    
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${springdoc.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.flexjson</groupId>
        <artifactId>flexjson</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.jws-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.activation-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15</artifactId>
        <version>1.46</version>
    </dependency>



    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.mlaccetti</groupId>
        <artifactId>javapns</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlgraphics-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
            
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>6.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
        <version>6.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    -->
    
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jasperreports-fonts</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.barcode4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>barcode4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.11</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
        <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrpc-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api.json</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.22</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>

    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>

    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf.tool</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlworker</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.7</version>
    </dependency>

    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>2.0.25</version> -->
        <version>2.0.30</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gcm</groupId>
        <artifactId>gcm-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.30</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.filenet</groupId>
        <artifactId>filenet-jace</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.filenet</groupId>
        <artifactId>filenet-pe</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.filenet</groupId>
        <artifactId>filenet-pe-resources</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.filenet</groupId>
        <artifactId>filenet-java-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.applicationservices</groupId>
        <artifactId>application.services</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
</dependencies>
```

and when trying to get a buffered image as follows:

```
public BufferedImage generateJasperReportPDF(JasperPrint jasperPrint, String fontName, String fontPath)
            throws IOException {
        JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
        BufferedImage bimage = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PDDocument document = null;
        try {


            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, outputStream);
            exporter.exportReport();

            document = PDDocument.load(outputStream.toByteArray());
            PDFRenderer renderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
            bimage = renderer.renderImageWithDPI(0, 300, ImageType.RGB);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception in generateJasperReportPDF: ", e);
        } finally {
            if (outputStream != null)
                outputStream.close();
            if (document != null)
                document.close();
        }
        return bimage;
    }
```

I am getting the following exception when the following line gets executed:

```
bimage = renderer.renderImageWithDPI(0, 300, ImageType.RGB);
```

Exception is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loading constraint violation when resolving method "javax/imageio/metadata/IIOMetadata.getAsTree(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/w3c/dom/Node;" : loader "com/ibm/ws/classloader/CompoundClassLoader@a24fe2b5" of class "org/apache/pdfbox/filter/DCTFilter" and loader "com/ibm/oti/vm/BootstrapClassLoader@9e7c1335" of class "javax/imageio/metadata/IIOMetadata" have different types for the method signature
    at org.apache.pdfbox.filter.DCTFilter.getNumChannels(DCTFilter.java:387) ~[pdfbox-2.0.30.jar:2.0.30]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.filter.DCTFilter.decode(DCTFilter.java:95) ~[pdfbox-2.0.30.jar:2.0.30]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSInputStream.create(COSInputStream.java:87) ~[pdfbox-2.0.30.jar:2.0.30]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.createInputStream(COSStream.java:175) ~[pdfbox-2.0.30.jar:2.0.30]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDStream.createInputStream(PDStream.java:243) ~[pdfbox-2.0.30.jar:2.0.30]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject.createInputStream(PDImageXObject.java:901) ~[pdfbox-2.0.30.jar:2.0.30]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.SampledImageReader.from8bit(SampledImageReader.java:507) ~[pdfbox-2.0.30.jar:2.0.30]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.SampledImageReader.getRGBImage(SampledImageReader.java:226) ~[pdfbox-2.0.30.jar:2.0.30]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject.getImage(PDImageXObject.java:514) ~[pdfbox-2.0.30.jar:2.0.30]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject.getImage(PDImageXObject.java:477) ~[pdfbox-2.0.30.jar:2.0.30]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PageDrawer.drawImage(PageDrawer.java:1116) ~[pdfbox-2.0.30.jar:2.0.30]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.graphics.DrawObject.process(DrawObject.java:67) ~[pdfbox-2.0.30.jar:2.0.30]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:958) ~[pdfbox-2.0.30.jar:2.0.30]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStreamOperators(PDFStreamEngine.java:531) ~[pdfbox-2.0.30.jar:2.0.30]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:506) ~[pdfbox-2.0.30.jar:2.0.30]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processPage(PDFStreamEngine.java:150) ~[pdfbox-2.0.30.jar:2.0.30]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PageDrawer.drawPage(PageDrawer.java:288) ~[pdfbox-2.0.30.jar:2.0.30]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer.renderImage(PDFRenderer.java:355) ~[pdfbox-2.0.30.jar:2.0.30]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer.renderImage(PDFRenderer.java:272) ~[pdfbox-2.0.30.jar:2.0.30]
    at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(PDFRenderer.java:258) ~[pdfbox-2.0.30.jar:2.0.30]
```

**UPDATE:** When inspecting Websphere Class loader viewer I found that the class IIOMetadata exists only once

```
 <class>
      <name>javax.imageio.metadata.IIOMetadata</name>
      <interface>false</interface>
   </class>
```

- The classloader order is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Looks like you have incorrect dependencies in your application. Add either pom.xml with dependencies or listing of your WEB-INF/lib folder. As it looks that your app is bundling unnecessary Java platform classes

Comment: @Gas I added the POM file

Comment: the jai dependencies (at least jai-imageio-core ) are missing, see https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/dependencies.html

Comment: Try to debug your classloading, look at this page https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/8.5.5?topic=ts-troubleshooting-class-loaders This `IIOMetadata` class is loaded twice, as this class is part of the JDK you need to look which of your application dependency has it also and remove that.

Comment: @Gas , IIOMetadata is a JDK class and I search through maven tree and it doesn't getting downloaded by any dependency

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr, the dependency you mentioned is optional not mandatory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is almost certainly duplicate visibility to the DOM class mentioned in the method signature, org/w3c/dom/Node. Given the description of the problem and the details in the exception text, I believe the following pattern is occurring:

1. The DCTFilter class is loaded from the parent-last application class loader. It references IIOMetadata and presumably calls the getAsTree() method on that class, which means it must also reference Node.
2. When dependencies are loaded, DCTFilter's class loader is used to load them. The ImageIO libraries are not packaged in the application (given your confirmation that they're loaded only once), and are found by the system class loader. The DOM classes are presumably packaged in the application, so Node is found in the application.
3. When the IIOMetadata class is linked and its dependencies loaded, the XML classes are found locally in the JDK, so a second instance of Node is found there.
4. DCTFilter now has visibility to two separate versions of org/w3c/dom/Node - directly, to the copy in the application, and indirectly, through IIOMetadata to the copy in the JDK. This is illegal, and the LinkageError is thrown.

The simplest solution is to remove the XML libraries from the application - JAXP has long been included in the JDK, and there's essentially never a reason that an application needs to bring its own version of this API. Removing the jar(s) containing the DOM classes should resolve that specific error.

A larger question may be why you're utilizing parent-last class loader delegation in the first place. While it is supported for some application packaging setups, it is basically the only way to end up with an error like this one, and usually an application is better off using the server's copy of the Java EE (and, in this case, SE) APIs than it is trying to bring its own. Unless you have a specific technical reason why you're using that configuration, the best solution might be to switch the class loader delegation back to the default.

Comment: I can't remove the xml-apis because xerces depends on it which is used internally by many other libraries like log4j, any other advice?
Also, I am using parent last because I am using some libraries that conflict with parent libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it as Jarid recommended by removing all the following conflicting libraries:

- xml-apis
- xercesImpl
- axis-jaxrpc

Comment: Glad to hear you were able to get it working!